# java out of memory : heap space with Tomcat 7 service

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to solve this issue which happens only during downloading any big file (size of 500mb). Currently what I have done is as follows

[image]

However I am still getting this error at my controller (I am using Spring MVC)

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.dnag2.controller.DownloadController.extractFile(DownloadController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

**UPDATED** (The function which loads the file)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}/d", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] extractFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\" + fileName);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""
                    + file.getName() + "\"");
            ;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

            while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
            return bytes;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
```

What else did I miss here ?

Comment: What's the code of the `com.dnag2.controller.DownloadController` ? Are you loading the whole file in memory ?

Comment: whats heap space settings? -Xmx

Comment: Updated my question with the related code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading the whole file in memory :

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
```

Of course this breaks. That's not how you handle downloads. You must write directly in the http answer stream.

Here's an example of a servlet doing it : http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

Comment: Had a same issue for java REST webservice..
Is there any way to solve this in REST ?